# How can I convert a date in string form ("Dec 25, 2012") into an group of integers (12/25/12)?

Tags: c++, function, parsing, pointers

I'm pretty new at programming, and my professor wants the class to write a function `GetDate(int *dptr, int *mptr, int *yptr)` that prompts user to enter a thr date as a string and output it as an integer where it returns these values through `dptr`, `mptr`, and `yptr`.  I don't understand pointers to this level yet (I understand the basics) and I just need support from anybody willing to help.  My code is also very inefficient and yea, I am aware that I did not use pointers and that the output is completely wrong but I'm trying.  I'm new so I may seem amateur but somebody help me out, please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void GetMonth() {
    string month;
    cout << "Please enter month: ";
    cin >> month;
    if (month == "jan")
    {
        cout << "01/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "feb")
    {
        cout << "02/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "mar")
    {
        cout << "03/"<< endl;
    }
    else if (month == "apr")
    {
        cout << "04/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "may")
    {
        cout << "05/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "june")
    {
        cout << "06/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "july")
    {
        cout << "07/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "aug")
    {
        cout << "08/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "sept")
    {
        cout << "09/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "oct")
    {
        cout << "10/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "nov")
    {
        cout << "11/" << endl;
    }
    else if (month == "dec")
    {
        cout << "12/" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string month;
    int day, year;
    GetMonth();
    cout << "Enter a day: ";
    cin >> day;
    cout << "Enter a Year: ";
    cin >> year;
    cout << "The date in int is: " << month << day << year << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

**********EDIT*******
I redid my whole code and did it with arrays but I still need help!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void readDate (char array[]);
void GetDate (char array[]);

const int size = 11;

int main ()
{
    char original[size];

    readDate(original); // call readDate
    GetDate(original); // call GetDate

    return 0;
}

void readDate (char array[])
{
    string month;
    cout << "Enter a date (Ex: Jan/20/2003): ";
    cin.getline (array, size); // read size characters into the character array
    cin >> month;
}

void getDate (char array[])
{   string month;
    string Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, July, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec;

    cout << "Date in converted format is: ";

    if (month == Jan) {
        cout << "01";
        }
    else if (month == Feb) {
        cout << "02";
        }
    else if (month == Mar) {
        cout << "03";
        }
    else if (month == Apr) {
        cout << "04";
    }
    else if (month == May) {
        cout << "05";
    }
    else if (month == Jun) {
        cout << "05";
    }
    else if (month == July) {
        cout << "07";
    }
    else if (month == Aug) {
        cout << "08";
    }
    else if (month == Sept) {
        cout << "09";
    }
    else if (month == Oct) {
        cout << "10";
    }
    else if (month == Nov) {
        cout << "11";
    }
    else if (month == Dec) {
        cout << "12";
    }

    cout << array[3] << array[4] << array[6] << array[7] << array[8] << array[9] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Instead of rolling your own, why not [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)?

Comment: I'll assume this question is about how to pass parameters to a function, and get a return value. You need a beginner's tutorial. (If you are asking about dates, use the standard library. Dates are way too tricky to do your own.) This is not a tutorial site, but we do answer specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but a specific question for me is how to convert the month as a string to an integer?

Comment: instead of cout << "12" try return 12;

Comment: You can convert a string to an integer using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). In this case, though, you should probably just read it in as an integer in the first place (change the type of `month` -- `cin >>` can handle integers just fine).

Comment: Unfortunately your professor is not teaching good programming skills, like the Single Responsibility Principle.  Here is the best implementation of your function: `bool GetDate(int *dptr, int *mptr, int *yptr) { std::string date_string = ReadLine(); return ParseDate(date_string, dptr, mptr, yptr); }`   Then you write a `ParseDate` function that completely avoids `cin` and `cout`, it is not responsible for input or output, only data processing.

Comment: Something else to consider is caseless string comparison. I.e, you want "Jan", "jan", "JAN", "jAN" etc to all be counted as intent to express the first month of the year. My suggestion is to think about converting the input string to either lowercase or uppercase before comparing to each of the elements of an array that contains lower or uppercase month names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are some code. it is intended to help you rather than to do it for you.

Try to study it and develop it. The code works correctly only if you input correct date format.

You can add some functions that would validate the input, and deal with different format possibilities like upper and lower case input.

note the `GetDate` is `bool` and currently return `true` only. You need to work and get it return false when needed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool GetDate(int *dptr, int *mptr, int *yptr)
{
    string date, day, month, year;

    cout << "\n Please enter a date: ";
    getline(cin, date);

    month = date.substr(0, 3);
    day = date.substr(4, 2);
    year = date.substr(8, 4);

    string month_array[12] = { "jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun",
                               "jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        if (month == month_array[i])
            *mptr = i + 1;

    *dptr = stoi(day);
    *yptr = stoi(year);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int day, month, year;
    int *d = &day, *m = &month, *y = &year;

    if (GetDate(d, m, y))
        cout << "\n\n\n date is:  " << *m << "/" << *d << "/" << *y;
    else
        cout << "incorrect date";

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My goodness, this actually starts to make sense.  I needed to make an array to hold 12 months and make a boolean function where the for loop will convert the months from string to int.  Then the outcome will be returned as a pointer in dptr, yptr, and mptr.  Apologies if this is incorrect but I'm a first-year cs student at a community college so I'm still in the learning phase.  I just looked at the output so I'm going to make changes so the years are returned in all 4 digits rather than 1 i.e; 2001 = 1.  Thanks for helping dude!

Comment: @Zack: The year is returned in 4 digits if it is entered in 4 digits. what you need to do is entering the date in this format: `jan 31, 2000` with writing  month in small letters and maintain the spaces. or writing more functions to validate the input and to accept more flexible input format. I can see you are a new member, so please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help)